# Sql server pulando id de registros

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Após alterar um registro na aplicação, o próximo registro que inseri na tabela pulou 1000 incrementações no id. id's

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
1015
1016
```

Comment: o que você quer é entender ou _resetar_? detalha melhor na pergunta..

Comment: outro ponto, foi feita alguma ação no banco que pode ter incrementado isso? tipo testes de performance??

Comment: Os dois, quero saber o porque está acontecendo e como resolver a situação, já tentei apagar os registros errados, mas a incrementação continua do maior registro que apaguei.

Comment: Eu crei um método para alterar o registro, após isso o problema aconteceu.

Comment: só é usada uma semente de um identity (estou supondo que o campo seja identity, parece meio óbvio mas na sua pergunta falta muita informação) quando tenta inserir um dado. Se deu erro nos inserts, o SQL já "usou" aquele próximo valor, provavelmente o que aconteceu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem [uma questão no *SOEN*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162648/sql-server-2012-column-identity-increment-jumping-from-6-to-1000-on-7th-entry) que responde bem este problema, caso esteja usando o *SQL Server 2012 +*:

> Este é um comportamento normal, visto que a Microsoft adicionou
>   *sequences* a partir do _SQL Server 2012, alterando a forma como as chaves são geradas (inclusive indica [este
>   link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/668042/SQL-Server-2012-Auto-Identity-Column-Value-Jump-Is)
>   que contém o detalhamento da implementação).

Na resposta indica como usar a "forma antiga" de geração, mas aconselho você manter a atual, visto que é mais performática. Caso precise de um sequencial *sem furos*, o ideal é criar um campo `codigo` (por expemplo) e controlá-lo como contador.

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/215800)

Comment: @JoãoMartins acredito que a resposta explica o _porquê_ do "pulo no id" independentemente do _link_, o que ao meu ver responderia a pergunta. Não?!

Comment: A meu ver não. O link que colocou para o **SOen** pode ajudar, mas não indica qual das respostas é que se deve focar (visto que todas as respostas à questão têm votos positivos), não colocou na sua resposta um trecho traduzido da resposta do *link* e para quem não lê inglês será difícil perceber o que a sua resposta pretende solucionar. Mas isso é a minha opinião.

Answer (score 4):

Complementando a resposta do rLinhares, esse problema pode acontecer em dois cenários:

(1) se está usando um campo IDENTITY a partir da versão 2012 quando o serviço é reiniciado o SQL faz um RESEED dos IDENTITY adicionando 1000. Muitos pensam que isso é um bug, mas não é.
(2) no uso de sequences com cache. Se a instância for reiniciada o número de itens que você tinha em cache da sequence são perdidos.

Para contornar o cenário 1 você pode habilitar o parâmetro -t272 como está no link citado na resposta anterior, porém eu não indicaria o controle manual desse campo por questões de performance.

Se você tiver que controlar manualmente isso, cada vez que for efetuar um INSERT, terá que fazer um SELECT antes que trará o "MAX + 1"

Espero ter ajudado